# HTML + CSS: background-size: cover; not working

Tags: css, background-size

My HTML contains several 100% width divs, which have background-image rules applied to them.
Each surrounding canvas div is position relative, while the background-image divs are position absolute.

There is a background-size: cover; applied to each background-image div, but this does not work for some reason.

Please check this page for example:
https://mitteiler-os.de/

The first two "slider" sections with background images applied show white bars to the left and right. These two sections have 1980x1000 px images applied to the background-image CSS, while the rest of the sliders further down have wider images applied to them.

Somehow I do not understand why background-size: cover is not working right here.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that it does work for me. !?
can't see any white bars on the left or the right.

One Side note, the page doesn't really adapt nice to smaller screens (mobile)

Comment: I just uploaded a different filesize (longest side 2048px).
The whitespace showed when I used images with 1980px width x 1000px height.
really odd.
I didnt code the theme.. and my job was just to find out why the theme would resize those full width images in frontpage to a very small image size and thus causes them to blur. I fixed that and didnt check anything else on the site ;)
but I will let the site owner know that responsive should be reworked.
Thanks for the heads-up.